# How can I connect the Nginx container to my React container?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have tried reading through the other stackoverflow questions here but I am either missing something or none of them are working for me.

### Context

I have two docker containers setup on a DigitalOcean server running Ubuntu.

`root_frontend_1 running on ports 0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp
root_nginxcustom_1 running on ports 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp`

If I connect to `http://127.0.0.1`, I get the default Nginx `index.html` homepage. If I `http://127.0.0.1:3000` I am getting my react app.

What I am trying to accomplish is to get my react app when I visit `http://127.0.0.1`. Following the documentation and suggestions here on StackOverflow, I have the following:

`docker-compose.yml` in root of my DigitalOcean server.

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginxcustom:
    image: nginx
    hostname: nginxcustom
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/root/nginxcustom/conf/custom.conf
    tty: true

  backend:
    build: https://github.com/Twitter-Clone/twitter-clone-api.git
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    tty: true

  frontend:
    build: https://github.com/dougmellon/react-api.git
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

`nginxcustom/conf/custom.conf` :

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name http://127.0.0.1;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://root_frontend_1:3000; # this one here
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, it builds but when I visit the ip of my server, it's still showing the default nginx html file.

### Question

What am I doing wrong here and how can I get it so the main URL points to my react container?

Thank you for your time, and if there is anything I can add for clarity, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: It looks like you're placing your nginx config file at `/root/nginxcustom/conf/custom.conf`, but you should actually place it at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. Can you check if that helps?

Comment: @NickODell still takes me to the default html page.

Comment: Configure the `proxy_pass` with the service name, not the container name i.e.: `proxy_pass http://frontend:3000`. Update your question with the `nginx` service logs if the issue persists.

Comment: @masseyb do I keep the " - ./nginx.conf:/root/nginxcustom/conf/custom.conf" line in my docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: No, and you shouldn't mount it to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` either imho - mount it to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` which is included by the default `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. Stop the service, remove the container then bring the service back up to make sure the changes take effect (i.e. `docker-compose stop nginxcustom && docker-compose rm -f && docker-compose up -d`).

Comment: So I had to create the conf.d folder and the default.conf file. Is that okay? Then I add that path to the volume? Trying that now. Thank you for your time. Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: No, just need to update `volumes` in your `docker-compose.yml` for the `customnginx` service i.e. replace `./nginx.conf:/root/nginxcustom/conf/custom.conf` with `./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` - the syntax is `[HOST_PATH]:[CONTAINER_PATH]`, the `/etc/nginx/conf.d` directory already exists inside the container containing the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` that we want to override with the bind-mounted file.

Comment: @masseyb so I replaced that with the volumes file and ran the docker-compose commands you posted but get this error: https://pastebin.com/raw/geEWUB0S

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222467/discussion-between-masseyb-and-dmellon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR;

The `nginx` service should [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) to the service name (`customnginx`), not the container name (`root_frontend_1`) and the `nginx` config should be mounted to the correct location inside the container.

***Tip***: the container name can be set in the `docker-compose.yml` for services setting the [`container_name`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name) however **beware** you can not [`--scale`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) services with a fixed `container_name`.

***Tip***: the container name (`root_frontend_1`) is generated using the [compose project name which defaults to using the current directory name if not set](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name).

***Tip***: the [`nginx`](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) images are packaged with a default `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` that will [include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) the default server config from `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`. You can [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) the default configuration files out of a container if you'd like to inspect them or use them as a base for your own configuration:

```
docker create --name nginx nginx
docker cp nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf default.conf
docker cp nginx:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf nginx.conf
docker container rm nginx
```

---

With `nginx` proxying connections for the `frontend` service [we don't need to bind the hosts port to the container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose), the services `ports` definition can be replaced with an `expose` definition to prevent direct connections to http://159.89.135.61:3000 (depending on the `backend` you might want prevent direct connections as well):

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  ...
  frontend:
    build: https://github.com/dougmellon/react-api.git
    expose:
      - "3000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Taking it a step further we can configure an [`upstream`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream) for the
`frontend` service then configure the `proxy_pass` for the `upstream`:

```
upstream frontend {
  server frontend:3000 max_fails=3;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name http://159.89.135.61;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend/;
  }
}
```

... then [bind-mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) the custom `default.conf` on top of the `default.conf` inside the container:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  nginxcustom:
    image: nginx
    hostname: nginxcustom
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    tty: true
```

... and finally `--scale` our `frontend` service (bounce the services removing the containers to make sure changes to the config take effect):

```
docker-compose stop nginxcustom \
&& docker-compose rm -f \
&& docker-compose up -d --scale frontend=3
```

`docker` will resolve the service name to the IP's of the 3 `frontend` containers which `nginx` will proxy the connections for in a (by default) round robin manner.

***Tip***: you can not `--scale` a service that has `ports` mappings, only a single container can bind to the port.

***Tip***: if you've updated the config and can connect to your load balanced service then you're all set to create a DNS record to resolve a hostname to your public IP address then update your `default.conf`'s [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

***Tip***: for security [I maintain specs for building a `nginx` `docker image`](https://github.com/masseybradley/nginx-modsecurity) with [Modsecurity](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity) and [Modsecurity-nginx](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity-nginx) pre-baked with the [OWASP Core Rule Set](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs).

Answer (score 0):

In Docker when multiple services needs to communicate with each other, you can use the service name in the url (set in the docker-composer.yml instead of the ip (which is attributed from the available pool of the network, default by default), it will automatically be resolve to the right container ip due to network management by docker.

For you it would be http://frontend:3000